# Prevent new users from being added to a group with the same name as user name and instead add to generic group?

Tags: permissions, users, groups, adduser

I need to add several new users to a system. Each of these users should be a member of the same group - `appdev` - and should not be assigned to a group that is the same as their user name.

Can I do this automatically so that I don't need to use the `-g` or `-G` parameters when using `adduser`. Ideally, this would be something I could do once so that all new users in the future are also automatically added to this generic group and a group would not be created that has the same name as the new user(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `/etc/adduser.conf` set `USERGROUPS` to `no` and `USERS_GID` to the GID of `appdev`.

Comment: Possibly the default *umask* needs to be adjusted as well.